# Filling field with JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to fill some fields with javascript (actually through an android aplication, but it doesn't matter here, because i'm having the same situation on my desktop).

Well, take a look:

> http://siga.ufjf.br
>
> `javascript: document.getElementById("user").value = "some text";`

It doesn't work. I really don't know why. I can fill many fields using this method, but i need to do this at http://siga.ufjf.br

Thx a lot !

Comment: Solved using this link: http://sigam2.ufjf.br/index.php ! Thank you all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that site uses frames, and you're probably executing the javascript on the main page, which doesn't have that input element

the frame, by the way is in in http://sigam2.ufjf.br/index.php - so cross origin rules will prevent you from accessing the frame easily

Comment: I don't know who is downvoting, but your answer is correct. Cross origin rules do apply. +1

Comment: Solved, thanks ! PS.: I didnt downvoted anyone !

Answer (score 1):

That should work, make sure that the `id = 'user'` really exists in your DOM.

```
var userObj = document.getElementById("user")
```

userObj is probably undefined and that's why you are not able to set the value.

Check your javascript console logs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at <anonymous>:2:39
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks ! I found my mistake: the field is inside some frames, and i can't just get that element. Do you know how can i acess that field through these frames ?

Comment: Put your code inside the frame source code

Comment: Solved, thanks ! And i didnt downvoted, if i did, my bad ! :/

Comment: awesome @VictorMilazzo please, select the most appropriate answer as the "selected answer" (green check).

Answer (score 0):

Your website, `http://siga.ufjf.br/` contains a frame to `http://siga3.ufjf.br`.

For security reasons, you can't execute any JavaScript if everything doesn't match. (siga != siga3)

[image]

The best solution is to enable CORs for your other domain.

If you're running PHP on your site, you can run something like:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siga.ufjf.br");
```

Which would allow your parent site to use JavaScript on the frame.